# Testing combined Rx and TPL

Tags: .net, unit-testing, task-parallel-library, system.reactive, scheduler

I'm struggling to get my head around how to make this test pass:

```
[Fact]
public void scheduler_test()
{
    var scheduler = new TestScheduler();
    var value1Set = false;
    var value2Set = false;

    Observable.Return(true)
        .Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100), scheduler)
        .Subscribe(_ => value1Set = true);

    Observable.Return(true)
        .Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100), scheduler)
        .Subscribe(async _ =>
        {
            await Task
                .Delay(500)
                .ContinueWith(__ => value2Set = true);
        });

    Assert.False(value1Set);
    Assert.False(value2Set);
    scheduler.AdvanceBy(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500).Ticks);
    Assert.True(value1Set);
    Assert.True(value2Set);
}
```

It currently fails on the final assertion. I thought that the `async` subscription would block until the awaited `Task` has completed, but that appears to not be the case.

Can anyone explain why this isn't working, and how one should go about testing a combined scenario such as this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the TPL with TestScheduler. Task.Delay will wait 500 *real* milliseconds, not simulated ones. You need to use an Rx-compatible version of Delay, something like `Observable.Timer`.

On an unrelated note, don't use async methods in the `Subscribe`, write something like this instead:

```
Observable.Return(true)
    .Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100), scheduler)
    .SelectMany(async _ => await Task.Delay(500))
    .Subscribe(
    {
        value2Set = true;
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, but that exhibits exactly the same behavior. That is, `value2Set` is `false` in the last assertion because the delay has not yet completed. Basically, I want the reactive pipeline to wait for the TPL task to complete before it considers itself "handled".

Comment: The 2nd part of my comment was more of a code review, it still wont work because of what I've mentioned above

Comment: By the way, I can get the test to pass by changing the subscribe to be non-async and to call `Wait()` on the `Task`, but I'm guessing that's a bad idea too because of blocking the thread and all.

Comment: The good news is that this code would work outside of TestScheduler (I.e. you can wait on things like that with SelectMany)

Comment: The bad news is that I can't fricken test it :(

Comment: If you want to make this work you either have to replace the TPL usage with Rx, or stop using TestScheduler and await things in actual time. Which one is best depends on how long your times are

Comment: Yeah, was just thinking as I was taking the bin out for collection: the TPL is from a 3rd party lib (and I think it's the right choice). I will just have my service that calls into said lib raise an event (or signal an observable) when the TPL operation completes. That way, my test can just start the test scheduler and then wait a reasonable time for the event to fire. Thanks Paul - appreciated.

Comment: No problem. The general theme is, TestScheduler doesn't have magic powers, it can only control Rx concurrency; anything involving Real Delays and Threads can't be simulated. In general, save TestScheduler for testing delays, you usually don't need it and it makes things more complex

Comment: Yeah, I think where I got confused was I was expecting the `async` subscription to automatically wait until the task completed, but that was a brain fart. Sorry, one more thing if you'd be so kind: can you elaborate on your point about using `SelectMany` rather than `Subscribe` to instigate an `async` method? My actual scenario is buffering then when the buffer fills, I need to call a method that returns `Task`. Why is `SelectMany` superior?